# for each of the following solve for x and y

Tags: quadratic-forms

Question 1- For each of the following equations
1.1 Solve for x

$$x^2-2xy+y^2=0$$
$$5x^2-3xy-8y^2$$
$$8x^2-5xy-13xy^2=0$$

Comment: Please share your attempts/ideas.

Comment: Hint: $x^2-2xy+y^2=(x-y)^2$

Comment: Do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: @LeeNeverGup It seems the hint is not very useful here in the following sense: given the level of the question, I believe the student has first to learn a general approach that can be used for all such equations equally. And then he/she might realize the shortcuts for "lucky" cases.

Comment: I believe the last one has a typo. Without $x$ in the last term the determinant is $441=21^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Use the quadratic formula
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
For 1, $a=1, b=-2y, c=y^2$

Use that same idea for the other 2

EDIT:  per @LeeNeverGup and @DanielLittlewood, it is worth mentioning that equation 1 is quite factorable.  In particular, quadratics of the form $x^2\pm2xy+y^2$ can be factored as $(x\pm{y})^2$.  You solve the equation by setting the equation equal to 0.  Thus
$$x^2-2xy+y^2=(x+y)^2$$
$$(x-y)^2=0$$
$$x-y=0$$
Thus, $x=y$

Comment: I think it's worth noting that for the first one you can simply say $(x-y)^{2}=0$

Comment: I do think that is good.  I will mention it.

Comment: He could factorize all of them

Comment: Yes, he could factor all of them.